# Select rows where column A and column B do not exist as a row in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3 
FROM TABLE_A 
WHERE NOT COLUMN1 IN (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE B)
```

But I need it to look at 2 columns rather than 1. It needs to Select rows no row in TABLE_B has those 2 values together.

Comment: can you provide some sample data and the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

```
Where (NOt Column1 IN (Select ..) Or Not Column2 IN (Select ..))
```

Or

```
Where NOt Column1 IN (Select ..) And Not Column2 IN (Select ..)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question right, this should work:

```
select COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
from TABLE_A
    left outer join TABLE_B
        on TABLE_A.COLUMN1 = TABLE_B.COLUMN1
            and TABLE_A.COLUMN2 = TABLE_B.COLUMN2
where TABLE_B.COLUMN1 is null
```

This is under the assumption that the columns involved in the `left outer join` do not allow `null` values. If there can be nulls involved it gets more complicated...